# Grafana - How to combine two different dashboards into a single dashboard please give me a any suggestion?

Tags: grafana

Small question regarding Grafana dashboards, please.

I have the JSON of PostgreSQL, the second dashboard is node-exporter.

so how do we combine the 2 dashboards into one dashboard?

I have also tried the merge the 2 JSON file into a single frame but the id is unique so how do we combine the id also.

can anyone help me out with this problem how I can resolve it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.